# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '12'.'

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, syntax-error

I'm a .Net beginner and I'm trying to create a simple EShop ASP.Net web application.

I've created a Class named FactorRepository and here is the code:

```cs
public class FactorRepository : IFactorRepository
    {
        private const string _connectionString = "ConntectionString";

        ICartRepository _cartRepository;
        IProductRepository _productRepository;

        public FactorRepository(ICartRepository cartRepository, IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            _cartRepository = cartRepository;
            _productRepository = productRepository;
        }

        public Factor CreateFactor(int cartId, int customerId)
        {
            Factor factor = new Factor();
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    customerId = 1;
                    var cart = _cartRepository.GetCartBy(1);
                    int totalPrice = cart.TotalPrice;
                    DateTime createdDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

                    sql.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = sql.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = $"Insert into Factors (CustomerId, TotalPrice, CreatedDate) values ({customerId}, {totalPrice}, {createdDate})";
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        factor.CustomerId = int.Parse(reader["CustomerId"].ToString());
                        factor.TotalPrice = int.Parse(reader["TotalPrice"].ToString());
                        factor.CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse(reader["CreatedDate"].ToString());
                    }
                    sql.Close();

                    return factor;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where am I going wrong and what is my problem/problems?

Comment: **Security Hazard: SQL Injection!** Don't use string interpolation to create SQL statements with your user data, use Parameters instead. (This will also fix the error you're getting now, BTW) For more information, you can read my blog post entitled [Back to basics: SQL Injection](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/)

Comment: By the way, an INSERT will not return any rows, so you don't need a reader. Use command. ExecuteNonQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add single quotes in dates `'{createdDate}'`
It would be better to use Command Parameter for passing value to avoid SQL Injection

```
command.CommandText = $"Insert into Factors (CustomerId, TotalPrice, CreatedDate) values ({customerId}, {totalPrice}, '{createdDate}')";
```